# adding a child to a child in Firebase Database with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with the following Firebase Database:

[image]

I add new chatIDs with the following code:

```
DatabaseReference.users(uid: self.uid).reference().child("chatIds/\(chat.uid)").setValue(chat.uid)
```

I need to add a single child to the individual `"chatIDs"` that is a random string that I will generate but I haven't worked with Firebase for that long so I am not sure how to do add children this far in. How can I write the code to do this?

Comment: Whats the question then? you have already answered it

Comment: you want to add child without setting Value ? or what is your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your database structure, a possible implementation of you want would be:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

// Generating the chat id
let refChats = ref.child("chats")
let refChat = refChats.childByAutoId()

// Accessing the "chatIds branch" from a user based on
// his id 
let currentUserId = self.uid
let refUsers = ref.child("users")
let refUser = refUsers.child(currentUserId)
let refUserChatIds = refUser.child("chatIds")

// Setting the new Chat Id key created before
// on the "chatIds branch"
let chatIdKey = refChat.key
let refUserChatId = refUserChatIds.child(chatIdKey)
refUserChatIds.setValue(chatIdKey)
```

Comment: Ok. I think I see this now. I will try it soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this

```
    let key = firebaseRef.child("users").child("\(String(describing: uid))").child("chatIds").childByAutoId().key

    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let child = ["key":key,
                 "name": name as String,
                 "date": birth as String,
                 "created": "\(timestamp)"]

    firebaseRef.child("users").child("\(String(describing: uid!))").child("chatIds").child(key).setValue(child)
```

as example I'm saving the key, name, date, and created, as Childs of chatIds, with the `childByAutoId`, that generates you a random key, so you can locate it when searching the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase

    class ChatListVC: UIViewController {
            var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
            var messages: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
            fileprivate var _refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.userDetail()
}
        func userDetail(){
        _refHandle = self.ref.child("users").child("child id").observe(.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                    guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else { return }
        //access data from dict

        let MyName = dict["MyName"] as? String ?? ""
         })
    }
```